# sed - how to display n-line from end of file?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to display 5th line from end of file, how can I do this using `sed`?

Comment: `sed` is not a good choice for this.. use `tail+head` combo... and please take time to go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Found it here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107387/emulate-tail-with-sed

Comment: @anonyXmous thx a lot, hard to find! So final answer for this can be: sed -e :a -e '$q;N;6,$D;ba' | sed -n '1p'

Comment: Wow, very re-usable and readable :D

Comment: This is not elegant, but usable without 'tail'

Comment: This is a duplicate of [emulate tail with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107387/emulate-tail-with-sed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here [emulate tail with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107387/emulate-tail-with-sed) – anonyXmous

So final answer for this can be: sed -e :a -e '$q;N;6,$D;ba' | sed -n '1p' – Eneen

Comment: There is no need for a second invocation of sed as using the `-n` option and replacing `q` with `P` achieves the required result i.e. `sed -n ':a;$P;N;6,$D;ba' file`

Answer (score -1):

Hi Use below command for your requirement.

```
  tail -5 yourfile.txt | sed -n "1p"
```

If you want to change the line to print just change `"5p"` like `"10p"` for 10th line `"3p"` to print 3rd line etc.

Or you can just use the combination of tail and head

```
  tail -5 yourfile.txt | head -1
```

Comment: This prints the 5th line from the top, not the bottom.

Comment: @SimonShine  Thanks  :-)

Comment: If you're going to use `tail` anyways, there's no reason to use sed: `tail -5 | head -1`. :) Also, the `"5p"`, `"10p"` suggestions aren't compatible with your line any more.

Comment: @SimonShine, never realized that. Thanks :-) Modified my answer